# Is it possible to create and name a folder on Google drive based on the contents of Gmail

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, gmail, drive

As title, it is possible to do that through APIs? I have tried both Drive APIs and Gmail API, but it doesn’t seem to work out

Comment: Possible. `````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: Yes it is possible. What did you try and didn't work out ?

Comment: ok thanks I will work hard on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes, it is possible!

You need to make use of the Gmail API first to get the data wanted.

For this, you can use the below request:

```
GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/USER_ID/messages/MESSAGE_ID
```

Where `USER_ID` is the email address of the user for which you need to get the data from.

Afterwards, you can do some data manipulation in order to get the *exact* part that is of interest to you and in order to create a folder using the Drive API, you can use the below request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
```

With the following body:

```
{
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}
```

#### Reference

- [Gmail API Method: users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get);
- [Create folders Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder).